# Haproxy backend server down due to layer 6 invalid response failed ssl handshake?

Tags: load-balancing, https, haproxy, openssl, ubuntu-14.04

We have two servers which are in different networks. We want to have ssl communication from client to front-end and from front-end   to back-end.

The front-end is able to receive and terminate ssl traffic, the back-end  ssl communication is not happening, with the following error:

"***Server nodes/web02 is DOWN, reason: Layer6 invalid response, info: "SSL handshake failure", check duration:546ms "***

haproxy config file:

---

```
global
  log 127.0.0.1 local1 debug
  maxconn 4000
  daemon
  uid 99
  gid 99
  stats socket /tmp/haproxy.stats level admin

defaults
  mode http
  log     global
  option forwardfor
  option http-server-close
  timeout server 5s
  timeout connect 5s
  timeout client 5s




frontend www-https
   bind  <Ip-address>:443 ssl crt /home/user/SSL/domain-name.in.pem
   reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
   default_backend nodes


backend nodes
   
    balance roundrobin
    cookie JSESSIONID prefix indirect nocache
   server web01 <IP-address>:8443 ssl verify none check cookie web01
    server web02 <IP-address>:8443  ssl  crt /home/SSL/domain-name.in.pem ca-file /home/SSL/gdig2.crt  verify required   check cookie web02
```

any help in this greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

> We want to have ssl communication from ... front-end to back-end

This makes no sense: there's no TCP communication between a haproxy frontend and a haproxy backend. It's a logical mapping internal to the haproxy process. Your actual backend TLS gets configured on the backend server itself `<IP-address>:8443` of `web02`.

So the `SSL handshake failure` you're getting stems from the fact HAproxy is unable to authenticate the cert of web02 using the given `ca-file` cert. Or your client authentication is failing (the one specified via `server web02 ... ssl crt ...`). Looking at the backend line:

```
server web02 <IP-address>:8443  ssl  crt /home/SSL/domain-name.in.pem ca-file /home/SSL/gdig2.crt  verify required   check cookie web02
```

Are you sure you meant to use client authentication? If yes, please verify your client certificate: it's very unusual to me to use the same certificate for client authentication which you also use for serving TLS in your frontend haproxy spec (`/home/SSL/domain-name.in.pem`).